# How to connect to k8s api server within a pod using k8s java client

Tags: java, kubernetes

## Context

I have a java application built as a docker image.

The image is deployed in a k8s cluster.

In the java application, I want to connect to the api server and save something in Secrets.

How can I do that with k8s java client?

## Current Attempts

The [k8s official document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) says:

> From within a pod the recommended ways to connect to API are:
>
> - run kubectl proxy in a sidecar container in the pod, or as a background process within the container. This proxies the Kubernetes API to the localhost interface of the pod, so that other processes in any container of the pod can access it.
> - use the Go client library, and create a client using the rest.InClusterConfig() and kubernetes.NewForConfig() functions. They handle locating and authenticating to the apiserver.

But I can't find similar functions neither similar examples in java client.

Comment: Please show your current attempts at the solution

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that your Pod has a `serviceAccount` automounted -- which is the default unless you have specified otherwise -- the [`ClientBuilder.cluster()`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/client-java-parent-2.0.0/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/util/ClientBuilder.java#L119) method reads the API URL from the environment, reads the cluster CA from the well known location, and similarly the `ServiceAccount` token from that same location.

Then, while not exactly "create a Secret," this [`PatchExample`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/client-java-parent-2.0.0/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/PatchExample.java) performs a mutation operation which one could generalize into "create or update a Secret."